# Call image in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, image

I want to ask.

I have table :

```
1. No = 01 
2. ID = 001
3. Password = 001
4. IMAGE = 001
```

I save my images in folder Images.

If I have 100 record how i call image at database?? but I wont change my table at database

I can call my image when I change my data in table

```
1. No = 01 
2. ID = 001
3. Password = 001
4. IMAGE = Images/001.jpg
```

Sample SCRIPT:

```
   $user =$_SESSION['username'];
   $data=mysql_query("select * from user WHERE ID=$user ");
   while($baris=mysql_fetch_array($data))
   {
      echo "<img src=\"$baris[IMAGE]\"> ";
   }
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: ___Warning :___ your code is vulnerable to [**SQL Injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) you need to escape  request properly and better approach would be prepared statements

Comment: Well now what is the problem?

Comment: problem solve...tq sonusindhu

Answer (score 4):

try to include in your path `Images` folder and include the file extension `'.jpg'` like:

```
$user =$_SESSION['username'];
$data=mysql_query("select * from user WHERE ID=$user ");
while($baris=mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
echo "<img src=\"Images/".$baris['IMAGE']."\">";

}
```

I strongly suggest that you also store the file extension (to handle `.png,.gif and .jpeg`) and don't use `mysql_*` instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
echo "<img src='Images/".$baris['IMAGE'].".jpg'> ";
```

And if you have saved the folder name,then use

```
echo "<img src='".$baris['IMAGE'].".jpg'> ";
```

I did'nt understand why you are storing image name without extension

Comment: because there are 300 record

Comment: And also I got downvote even...What is the reason can tell me..??

Comment: yes it work, but if there a solution script ... i will use it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$user =$_SESSION['username'];
$data=mysql_query("select * from user WHERE ID=$user ");
while($baris=mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
  echo "<img src='Images/".$baris[IMAGE].".jpg'> ";

}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: @DonyAditya thanks. Why we getting downvote if my code is working

Comment: the moderator will handle in that complain @sonusindhu